# R interpret predictions weekly and monthly stock price returns

Tags: r, predictive-models

I have built a model in R that predicts weekly and monthly returns of stock prices using regression trees, roughly based on https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-cart-for-stock-market-forecasting/. In my training and test sets weekly and monthly return rates (the target variables) are calculated for Fridays as follows:

- Weekly: (Friday close - Monday open) / Monday open
- Monthly: (Last Friday of the month close - first Monday of the month 
  open) / first Monday of the month open

Weekly returns are available for each Friday of the week and monthly returns are available for each last Friday of the month.

Using the predictive model, I can then predict weekly and monthly returns using the data available today. E.g. if today's data is xyz then the model predicts a weekly return of 0.1 and a monthly return of -0.02.

```
df_test$pred_weekly_return <- predict(tree_weekly,df_test)
df_test$pred_monthly_return <- predict(tree_monthly,df_test)
```

I am struggling with how to interpret these predicted weekly and monthly returns. If I use today's Wednesday 14 December data, is the predicted weekly return then for next week Wednesday 21 December or for this week Friday 16 December? And is the predicted monthly return then for the end of this month 31 December or, say, 31 days from now 13 January?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please do not cross-post. That is against SE policy & wastes a lot of people's time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is cross posted on [quant.SE] [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/31489).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of problems like this, one doesn't generally calculate weekly, monthly, or annual returns in the way you have described.  Normally, you set up your dataset so that each record is one trading day.  Then, to calculate the forward-looking weekly return, you look forward five trading days and calculate $(P_{d+5}-P_{d}+d_{d,d+5})/P_d$, where $d_{d,d+5}$ is any dividends paid between days $d$ and $d+5$.  Monthly returns are $(P_{d+21}-P_{d}+d_{d,d+21})/P_d$.  Quarterly returns are $(P_{d+63}-P_{d}+d_{d,d+63})/P_d$.  Annual returns are $(P_{d+252}-P_{d}+d_{d,d+252})/P_d$.  Then, when you run your regressions or whatever, you keep all the days in the dataset.  This means that the periods will overlap.  No biggie.

Now, you might object that sometimes there are fewer than 5 trading days in a week, that there might be more or less than 252 trading days in a year, etc.  That's right.  The method described above is going to make little bitty errors like that.  For most purposes, it doesn't matter.  And getting it exactly right is a big pain.  If you are really worried about it, you can but in dummy variables for things like day of week, month of year, whether the period has a trading holiday in it, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about forward looking returns. Problem solved!